# Win32 Global Key Hook / SetWindowsHook / GetAsyncKeyState sometimes not working

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex, wh-keyboard-ll

I have a question regarding hooks of Virtual Keys. I'd like to define global shortcuts for my application ( RegisterHotkey is not sufficient ). However, I tried two ways to implement the shortcuts:

1. I registered a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook. I put all the hooking code into a DLL and its working fine! 
   But: When special applications ( e.g. CCleaner ) have focus, the hook does not work any more! Nothing arrives at my application. I tried it with 32 and 64 Bit DLL.
2. I tried to solve the problem by frequently calling GetAsyncKeyState instead of using the hook. Also this version works well, until special applications ( again CCleaner ) gets the focus. In this moment GetAsyncKeyState returns 0 for all keys, even when they are pressed.

Does anyone have an idea how this problem can be fixed ?

By the way, it seems that the applications who disable my hook are written in Delphi are something else. These "Evil" applications do furthermore not react on any input, meaning a ShowWindow call on the windows of these applications does have not effect. The same for SetWindowLong and so on.

Thanks very much for your response!

Comment: Uninstall programs that give you headaches like this.  CCleaner ought to be high on that list anyway, it sells snake-oil.

Comment: Sure it's not just elevated programs? They're off limits to normal programs.